# Different scores when training XGBoost models in different machines

Tags: python, xgboost

On trying XGBoost's Demo on Ranking feature that it has: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/tree/master/demo/rank

There different prediction scores that generated on different machines. Is that expected?

I have run the same scripts on different machines:

1. Local Macbook environment
2. Amazon Linux in the remote environment), and the output that gets written to the file: `pred.txt`

Sample output of the script in the `demo/rank` example:

```
bash-4.2# ./runexp.sh
[01:13:08] 9630x47 matrix with 233775 entries loaded from mq2008.train
[01:13:08] 471 groups are loaded from mq2008.train.group
[01:13:08] 2707x47 matrix with 64764 entries loaded from mq2008.vali
....
....
[01:13:08] 2874x47 matrix with 71241 entries loaded from mq2008.test
[01:13:08] 156 groups are loaded from mq2008.test.group
[01:13:08] start prediction...
[01:13:08] writing prediction to pred.txt
```

The output in the Amazon Linux Machine

```
bash-4.2# head pred.txt
0.78357064724
0.16863465309
0.71193027496
0.68881440163
```

The output on MacBook

```
% head pred.txt
0.72682631016
0.15482419729
0.65316188335
0.67612731457
```

The same XGBoost code has been compiled on both machines (using `build.sh` in the root XGBoost folder).

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration file https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/demo/rank/mq2008.conf does not seem to fix the random seed. So even on the same machine running twice should lead to slightly different result (and scores) due to difference in sampling. The size of the variation depends on the data and (to a lesser extend, i think) on the model parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - we have tried setting the seed to, and it's the same behaviour. So that does not seem to be the problem. Moreover, [in documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html), the default random seed is 0. We have also done multiple runs of the Algorithm on the same machine, and the results are exactly the same, always!

Comment: @ramakrishna-nalam Have you found the reason or solution for this?